Modify GtkCombobox visual
I am having difficulties with the design of my HMI.
I'm using GTK 3.5 with Glade. I added a GtkCombobox inside a GtkStack and I would like to modify its visual and add a colored background.
In my .css file, I already used the following lines:
combobox > box.linked > button.combo > box {
      background-color: white;
}

This allows me to modify the background color of the button with the arrow and the entry but not of the entire combobox (I still have a gray part). If I only use the "combobox" class or the one before "box", it changes the color behind the combobox but not inside.
I even looked in the GTK 3 source files to have access to the combobox.nodes file, but I can't find a class that modifies the entire GtkCombobox background.
